# How can i divert calls from my phone to a different phone

Tags: calls, mobile-network

I want to know if its possible to divert calls from my current phone to a different phone using different numbers.Anybody got help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want call forwarding, which allows you to send incoming calls on phone number 1 to phone number 2.

You can set this in the standard Phone application. 
Phone App -> Settings -> Call Settings -> Call Forwarding

Answer (score 0):

I think i have got the answer to my question;

Setting up Call Forwarding with shortcodes
Dial **21* followed by the number you wish the calls to forwarded to, followed by # 
for example **21*13106565655#
Press 'yes/ok/send'
You will either see a message on your screen or receive a text message saying that forwarding has been enabled
Restart your phone
When you wish to stop forwarding your calls, dial ##21# to disable call forwarding
http://www.callforwardinginstructions.com/